# Generate APK File From Ubuntu Terminal Gradle Build

Tags: android, gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.takeimage"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    compile 'org.glassfish.main:javax.annotation:4.0-b33'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

}
```

1. This is My Build.Gradle file of my project.
2. Here I'm trying to generate apk file from ubuntu terminal using gradle build.
3. But the Gradle Build Failed........
4. I Don't have Android Studio
5. I have only Android sdk.
6. My main task is to generate apk file with out launching android studio.
7. From terminal
8. ./gradlw assemble Debug using this cmd.
9. Here is my log........

---

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:design:23.1.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.1/design-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.1/design-23.1.1.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/design/23.1.1/design-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/design/23.1.1/design-23.1.1.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/design/23.1.1/design-23.1.1.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/design/23.1.1/design-23.1.1.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.4.0/play-services-base-8.4.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/8.4.0/play-services-plus-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/8.4.0/play-services-plus-8.4.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/8.4.0/play-services-plus-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/8.4.0/play-services-plus-8.4.0.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/8.4.0/play-services-plus-8.4.0.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/8.4.0/play-services-plus-8.4.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.4.0/play-services-auth-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.4.0/play-services-auth-8.4.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.4.0/play-services-auth-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.4.0/play-services-auth-8.4.0.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.4.0/play-services-auth-8.4.0.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.4.0/play-services-auth-8.4.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v13/23.1.1/support-v13-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v13/23.1.1/support-v13-23.1.1.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/23.1.1/support-v13-23.1.1.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/23.1.1/support-v13-23.1.1.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/support-v13/23.1.1/support-v13-23.1.1.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/support-v13/23.1.1/support-v13-23.1.1.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-appindexing/8.4.0/play-services-appindexing-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-appindexing/8.4.0/play-services-appindexing-8.4.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-appindexing/8.4.0/play-services-appindexing-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-appindexing/8.4.0/play-services-appindexing-8.4.0.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-appindexing/8.4.0/play-services-appindexing-8.4.0.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-appindexing/8.4.0/play-services-appindexing-8.4.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.jar
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.pom
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.4.0/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified
  >   Could not find any matches for com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23) as no versions of com.android.support:support-v4 are available.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
  >        http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/android/support/support-v4/
  >    Required by:
  >        Android:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

1. Can any one help me to solve this issue.
2. I'm very much thankful to you.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the Android Repository and Google Repository installed in your SDK Manager, or they are not up to date with the latest updates.

Comment: Thanks boss you save my day

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/ubuntudb/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
 at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:163)
 at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:106)
 at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a 64bit system and still some 32bits are missing for android development.

If you're running on a 64bit-Ubuntu system, see 32-bit-libs for Ubuntu 64-bit Android Development for further details.

If you're running on a 64bit-Fedora system, see installing-android-sdk-on-64-bit-fedora/ for further details.

To get aapt working (this fixed my issues with the avd as well) just run these two commands:
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some support libraries locally. Have you tried running this once from the terminal?

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tool,extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-google-m2repository,android-23
```